# Can I update the value of a column based on the same column value in a python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe to capture characteristics of people accessing a webpage. The list of time spent by each user in the page is one of the characteristic feature that I get as an input. I want to update this column with maximum value of the list. Is there a way in which I can do this?

Assume that my data is:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({Page_id:{1,2,3,4}, User_count:{5,3,3,6}, Max_time:{[45,56,78,90,120],[87,109,23],[78,45,89],[103,178,398,121,431,98]})
```

What I want to do is convert the column Max_time in df to Max_time:`{120,109,89,431}`

I am not supposed to add another column for computing the max separately as this table structure cannot be altered.

I tried the following:

```py
for i in range(len(df)):
     df.loc[i]["Max_time"] = max(df.loc[i]["Max_time"])
```

But this is not changing the column as I intended it to. Is there something that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Page_id':[1,2,3,4],'User_count':[5,3,3,6],'Max_time':[[45,56,78,90,120],[87,109,23],[78,45,89],[103,178,398,121,431,98]]})
df.Max_time = df.Max_time.apply(max)
```

Result:

```
   Page_id  User_count  Max_time
0        1           5       120
1        2           3       109
2        3           3        89
3        4           6       431
```

Comment: Thank you @Stef. Yes this works. I understand that using apply or map might have been an easier solution now. Do you think there was some issue in the call using loc[i]?

Comment: The issue with your code is that `df.loc[i]["Max_time"]` is a **copy** of a slice and your assign the new value to that copy, not to the orginal df. See [Returning a view versus a copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) for details. Your code would work when you used `df.loc[i,"Max_time"] = ...` instead of `df.loc[i]["Max_time"] = ... `. The idiomatic way to do it in pandas is however to avoid iterating over rows and use apply or similar methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
df['Max_time'] = df['Max_time'].map(lambda x: np.max(x))
```